# Input Radio com valor default

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs

Usando Asp.Net MVC 5 com AngularJS quero que um `input radio` venha checado por default.

Segundo os link:

[How to select a radio button by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592345/how-to-select-a-radio-button-by-default)

[Assign an initial value to radio button as checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked)

Basta usar isto:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="ViewBag.Imposto.calcular" value="false">
    Não
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="ViewBag.Imposto.calcular" value="true" checked="checked">
    Sim
</label>
```

Porém não esta funcionando, como resolver isto?

**Editado**

Com pode ser visto na imagem, mesmo usando o código acima a opção não fica marcada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funciona para mim... (https://jsfiddle.net/opo1udff/). O que dizes não estar a funcionar?

Comment: O meu jsFiddle ( em cima ^ ) funciona no teu browser?

Comment: @Sergio Retirei a referência do AngulaJS `ng-model="ViewBag.Imposto.calcular"` e funcionou. Agora fiquei mais confuso ainda! kkk

Comment: Então usa `ng-checked="true"`, funciona?

Comment: @Sergio Matou a charada! É isso mesmo. Estava procurando por algo assim e não achei. Elabora uma resposta para que eu possa marcá-la como correta. E muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que tens de usar a [API do Angular - ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked), e fazer o input *checked* com

```
ng-checked="true"
```